# Writing to a file using exec

Tags: c, exec

I want to write to a text file I created using the `exec` function

What I tried so far:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
dup2(fd[1],1);
char * echo_args[] = {"/bin/echo" , "I want to write this >> ~/.filename", NULL};
execv(echo_args[0], echo_args);
```

This resulted in the following output **in the terminal**:

`I want to write this >> ~/.filename`

I am aware that there is an issue that is in the formatting as usually when using `echo` I need my text to be between quotations and the array needs the whole command between quotations, however using `char * echo_args[] = {"/bin/echo" , " "I want to write this" >> ~/.filename", NULL}` resulted in compilation errors which are the following :

```
test.c:103:42: error: expected '}'
   char * echo_args[] = {"/bin/echo" , ""I want to write this">> ~/.file...
                                         ^
test.c:103:25: note: to match this '{'
   char * echo_args[] = {"/bin/echo" , ""I want to write this">> ~/.file...
```

Any idea on what I can do to fix this or any alternative way to write a text to a file using exec?
Also, I am aware there is file functionalities in C without needing `exec` or any of this but I need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need double quotes inside a string you can escape them with `\"`.

```
char * echo_args[] = {"/bin/echo" , "\"I want to write this >> ~/.filename\"", NULL};
```

Comment: This didn't fix my issue even though the file compiled. 
My output was to the screen as well.

Comment: You are creating a "hidden" files in your /home directory since the filename starts with a '.' , have you checked using for example ls -a ?